# Using python selenium to do a timed scrapying task, and not close the driver. But the current webpage will contains the previous webelement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Using python selenium to do a timed scraping task, and not close the driver. But I found that the current webpage will contains the previous webelement which makes me wrongly point the element. **What caused this problem? and how can I deal with that?**

How I do timed task:

```
#  Create an instance of the Handler class
handler = Handler()

#  Schedule the run method to be executed every 1 minute
schedule.every(0.3).minutes.do(handler.run)

#  Run the scheduled tasks indefinitely
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

- I tried to close the driver every time, but it will raise an connection error the second time, like this:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=1217): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/b0d8a06b4eb8cadcc80f1df97c1e5673/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000000000885E08>: Failed to establish a new connection
```

- I also tried to clear cookies and browser cache everytime before I driver.get a new url, like this:

```
#  Clear cookies
self.driver.delete_all_cookies()

#  Clear browser cache
self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.clear();")
self.driver.execute_script("window.sessionStorage.clear();")
self.driver.execute_script("window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb');")
```

But both of the method are not work.

Comment: Please provide more details on what element holds the previous value. You can try nullifying existing web element every iteration.